# unrecognized selector sent to class in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

this is my class

#import "Year2011.h"

```
@implementation Year2011

- (void)Men:(double)speed{
    if (ramspeed <= 180000) {
        cal = 0;
    }
```

here i have HelloViewController class how can i call Year2011 class and Men mathod.
now i tried like this.

`@class Year2010`;

```
 IBOutlet Year2010 *Year2010;
```

calling

```
double speed=([anualIncome.text doubleValue]);
[Year2010 Men:income];
```

this one is showing `unrecognized selector sent to class`err.guide me i'm new to objective c.

Comment: Have you declared `Men:` method in your `.h` file? And I think you should replace your object name from `Year2010` to `year2010`.

Comment: Why do you need an IBOutlet for Year2010?

Comment: A note on naming conventions: methods should always start with lowercase letters.

Comment: The `unrecognized selector` exception tells you *which* selector was unrecognized. Was it `Men:` or actually `text` or `doubleValue` ?

Comment: @DarkDust particularly so in this case, as the compiler has no way of knowing if a class method or instance method is being called.

Comment: I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out what this code is supposed to be a part of.

Comment: @jrturton: The compiler picks "instance" in the ambiguous case. At least, LLVM 2.1 does. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up Class name and Instance name. You also seem to have problems understanding the scope of an instance.

-1- change your instance name to lowercase initial - that is `IBOutlet Year2010 *year2010;`

-2- change your method names to lowercase initial - that is `- (void)men:(double)speed`

The compiler currently assumes that Men is a static class method, but you never defined it as such, hence the error.

Comment: thank you so much its working fine.but i print something in side of that method its did't show in output.

Answer (score 4):

```
[Year2010 Men:income];
```

From the code you've shown us, the `Year2010` class doesn't have a method `Men:`. Why would you expect to be able to call it?

Maybe change the type of the variable `Year2010` to `Year2011`?

Also, dear god, don't name your instances the same as your classes. This will be impossible to read and understand when you come back from lunch, let alone months from now.